# Multiplicity of distinguishable particles

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have a problem in mind. There are 2 particles in a box. If they are distinguishable, there are 4 microstates represented by the picture below. If the particles are indistinguishable, there are only 3 microstates available (since the two states that are the lowest on the figure are the same state).
What I find strange is that if you want to count the probability to find 2 particles in the same half of the box at the same time, it is different for the two cases.

For the distinguishable case it is 1/2.
For the indistinguishable case it is 2/3.

If the particles are just moving there randomly, why should the system care if the particles are distinguishable or not. If we are to make measurements why should we see that in the indistinguishable case particles will occur at the same side of the box more often that in the distinguishable case?

[image: 2 distinguishable particles]

Comment: *If the particles are just moving there randomly, why should the system care if the particles are distinguishable or not.* Notice that this is a property independent of the details of your system (for the given situation). Which means it is inherently a statistical property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your question, you have implicitly assumed that the particles are bosons, and not fermions. If the particles were fermions, the only allowed microstate would be for the two particles to be in separate boxes. Then the probability for the two particles to be in separate boxes would be 1.

What you are discovering is a "statistical force" involving indistinguishable particles. This appears in many other contexts in statistical mechanics. Roughly speaking, quantum statistics leads to an extra effective attraction between identical bosons, and effective repulsion between identical fermions. In your example, this effective attraction leads to a larger probability of finding two bosons in the same box, compared to the case with indistinguishable particles. On the other hand, for the fermion example, the effective repulsion leads to a smaller probability (in fact zero probability) of the two particles being in the same box.

I think one reason your question may be counter-intuitive is that, by working with 2 boxes, you have chosen an example in which quantum effects are, in some sense, very large. In particular, the effective bosonic attraction is very large. What your example essentially enforces by having so few allowed position states, is that the separation of the particles is never very large compared to the Compton wavelength of the particles.

We can see this more explicitly by generalizing your example, to consider 2 particles and $N$ boxes, which live on a line. Each particle can be in one of the $N$ boxes. I claim that the "classical limit" in which quantum effects are small, is the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$.

- For *distinguishable* particles, there are $N^2$ microstates. This is because are $N$ choices for where to place particle 1, and $N$ choices for where to place particle 2. Meanwhile, the probability $p$ that two particles will be in the same box is $1/N$. This is because are $N$ microstates where both particle 1 and 2 are in the same box, and $N^2$ total microstates, so $p=N/N^2=1/N$. As a sanity check, we recover your result $p=1/2$ when $N=2$. In the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$, where the two particles can explore a large space, the probability of a collision becomes vanishingly small: $p\rightarrow 0$.
- For *indistinguisable bosons*, there are $N(N+1)/2$ microstates. There are $N$ ways to choose the box for boson 1. For boson 2, there are $N-1$ ways to choose a box different from boson 1; however for each of these states we must divide by 2 to account for the indistinguishable nature of the bosons. Then there is 1 way2 to choose a box where the second boson is in the same box as the first. Putting this together, $N(N-1)/2+N=N(N+1)/2$. Meanwhile, there are $N$ microstatses where the 2 bosons are in the same state. We then have $p=2/(N+1)$. When $N=2$, we get $p=2/3$ as you computed. When $N\rightarrow \infty$, we have $p\rightarrow 0$, and therefore in the "classical limit" the effect of indistinguishability goes away. However, there is still some small residusal effect, since asymptotically for large $N$, $p \sim 2/N$ is a bit larger than the indistinguishable particle case, due to the statistical attraction.
- For *indistinguishable fermions*, there are $N(N-1)/2$ microstates. We have $N$ choices for where to put the first fermion. There are then $N-1$ choices for where to put the second fermion, since two fermions can't live in the same state. There are 0 states where the 2 fermions are in the same box. In the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$, we recover the limit obtained in the above two examples. Again there is still some residual statistical effect, since for large $N$, $p=0$, which is less than the distinguishable case, due to the statistical repulsion.

Comment: More general case for $G$ particles (including $G=2$) for bosons  is well known:    $\frac {(G+N-1)!}{G!(N-1)!}$

Comment: It seems to me that it would be more appropriate to calculate in your model (N cells, 2 particles ) the probability of both particles falling into one or the other half of the linear set of cells. For distinguishable particles, this will be $p_{1/2}=2 \frac{(N/2)^2}{N^2}=\frac{1}{2}$ The same goes for bosons and fermions under high $N$

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist Right, so I did sneakily choose an interpretation of the problem, based on how the states were counted in the original question. In particular, I am taking the model to be a lattice of $N$ sites, and the only information is whether the particle is on the site, or not (the site has no "size"). If we really want to discuss physical boxes that have a finite volume, then I agree we'd want to set the problem up differently. But, in my opinion, this obscures the core conceptual point expressed in the original question.

Comment: However it is nice to point out that $p_{1/2}$ is exactly $1/2$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$. It is consistent with what I wrote, but I think captures the intuition the OP had. The microstates that would cause $p_{1/2}$ would differ from $1/2$ are precisely the "collision states" with two particles on one site. These become exceedingly rare in the limit of large $N$. This is basically what I meant by saying the original question is counterintuitive with 2 boxes, because the small number of sites makes the probability of a collision larger, and therefore quantum statistics more important.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you very much for your answer. I have not encountered the term "statistical force" before. Also, I have come across the Fermionic repulsion many times, but I have never thought of/seen the Bosonic attraction. Would you recommend some literature where this formalism is introduced? It seems to be taken for granted even in very basic books on Statistics.

Comment: @CHILLQQ Here is a wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction, there are also some references to books and papers linked from there.

Comment: @Andrew what if we do not consider quantum mechanical effects here? Can we imagine that those are just classical particles in a box? Indistinguishable particles could be e.g oxygen molecules, and distinguishable would be a mix of oxygen and nitrogen. Will the same effect be present ?

Comment: @CHILLQQ Classically there isn't really a notion of indistinguishable particles. We could always choose to paint one of the particles red and the other blue. In quantum mechanics, the state must be symmetric (or anti-symmetric) under exchange of any two identical particles. There isn't an analogue of this process in classical mechanics. Griffifths gives a good discussion of this, if you have access to that book.